# Use email template for contact form using Express/Sendgrid

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, sendgrid

I have a simple contact form using the [Node Sendgrid helper library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs).

I would like to use a template `email/contact.jade` that compiles to HTML and adds the right context. I know it needs to go in the `payload.html` value, however I'm stuck on how to send the email with the template.

**routes.js**

```
app.route('/contact')
  .post(function(req, res) {
    var template = 'email/contact.jade';

    var payload = {
      to: req.body.email,
      from: 'example@example.com',
      subject: req.body.subject,
      html: req.body.message
    };

    var email = new sendgridClient.Email(payload);

    sendgridClient.send(email, function(err, json) {
      if (err) { 
        return console.error(err);
      } else {
        res.redirect('/thanks');
      }
    });
  });
```

**email/contact.jade**

```
p Thanks
p Name {{ name }}
p Email {{ email }}
p Subject {{ subject }}
p Message {{ message }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'm not sure your jade syntax is correct. You could try this instead:

**email/contact.jade**

```
p Thanks
p Name #{name}
p Email #{email}
p Subject #{subject}
p Message #{message}
```

And to render this into HTML:

```
var jade = require('jade');
var templatePath = __dirname + '/contact.jade';

app.route('/contact')
  .post(function(req, res) {    
    var payload = {
      to: req.body.email,
      from: 'example@example.com',
      subject: req.body.subject,
      html: jade.renderFile(templatePath, req.body)
    };
    //...
  });
```

Comment: You're right about the jade template. However, I had to do this in order to get it to work: `var template = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/contact.jade')`, because I kept getting ' ENOENT, no such file or directory'

Comment: Could I also just do `html: jade.renderFile(__dirname + '/contact.jade', req.body)`. Using the `renderFile` method http://jade-lang.com/api/

Comment: Yes, `renderFIle` works too, and is probably even better since it makes it easier for jade to cache your templates. I've edited my answer a bit to take this into account.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. I'm guessing you wouldn't need the `fs` library or the `var template = 'email/contact.jade'` statement.

Comment: I've cleaned up the answer further. If you think its helpful upvote/mark as answer so others can see :)